# Bug with Iterating over a string c++

Tags: c++, string, loops, split

so I have a function called split_alpha() that takes in a std::string and splits the string into words, using any non-alphaneumeric character as a delimiter. It also maps the words to their lower-cased versions.

```
vector<string> split_alpha(string to_split) {

    vector<string> results;
    string::iterator start = to_split.begin();
    string::iterator it = start;
    ++it;
    //get rid of any non-alphaneumeric chars at the front of the string
    while (!isalnum(*start)) {
        ++start;
        ++it;
    }

    while (it != to_split.end()) { 
        if (!isalnum(*it)) {
            string to_add = string(start, it);
            lower_alpha(to_add);
            results.push_back(to_add);
            ++it;
            if (it == to_split.end()) { break; }
            while (!isalnum(*it)) {
                ++it;
                if (it == to_split.end()) { break; }
            }
            start = it;
            ++it;
        }
        else {
            ++it;
            if (it == to_split.end()) { break; }
        }
    }

    //adds the last word
    string to_add = string(start, it);
    lower_alpha(to_add);
    results.push_back(to_add);

    return results;
}
```

The function works fine 99% of the time, but when I give it the string "Sending query: “SELECT * FROM users”" (not including the quotations around the whole string), it does something really weird. It essentially goes into an infinite loop (within that while loop) and never finds the end of the string. Instead it keeps reading random characters/strings from somewhere?? My vector ends up with a size of about 200 before it finally segfaults. Anyone know what could be causing this? I tried printing out the string and it seems perfectly fine. Once again, the code works on every other string I've tried.
Thanks!!

Comment: for clarification, I have spent the past 2 days trying to debug this problem using my IDE (xcode) I've stepped through 100 times (which is how I found out it was reading random characters and not reaching the end of the string), its also how I found out that my code works on every other string. i also printed out every string my code iterates over and they all seem normal. I don't appreciate the assumption that I would post this without trying any kind of debugging.

Comment: Whenever you increment an iterator or a pointer you must check that the result of the increment is valid before you use it.

Comment: isn't the while loop doing that? it checks that the iterator is not off the end of the string before it executes any code (at least thats what i thought)

Comment: You increment the iterator multiple times within the loop, without checking that the result is  valid.

Comment: As @NeilButterworth said, be careful about walking off the end of the string. For example, `while (!isalnum(*it)) { ++it; }` doesn't check for the end of the string.

Comment: oh youre right! ok I updated my code (see update to original question), but its still reading off the end of my string...

Comment: oh, also for clarification lower_alpha() just maps all upper cased letters to lower case, and deletes any non-alphanumeric characters

Comment: Your second `break` statement will break out of nested `while` loop but not out of the main one. And since you `++` the iterator straight after, the main loop will fail to terminate as your iterator will have had passed the `to_split.end()`

Answer (score 0):

> isn't the while loop doing that?

Yes, but you can have several **++it** triggering before the **while** loop check, and in any one of those cases the iterator could already be at the end of the string. Most likely the other strings you tried did not cause a failure because they all end with an alphanumeric character.

Invert the order of the **++it** and the check:

```
if (it == to_split.end()) { break; }
++it;
```

Explanation: the following assert will fail, as the iterator will no longer be pointing to the end of the string (but one character further):

```
if (it == to_split.end())
{
    ++it;
    assert(it == to_split.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the origin of the bug in your function has been pointed out already, may I suggest slightly different approach to your word splitting, using regex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

std::vector<std::string> split_alpha(std::string str)
{
    std::regex RE{ "([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" }; // isalnum equivalent
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    // find every word
    for (std::smatch matches; std::regex_search(str, matches, RE); str = matches.suffix())
    {
        //push word to the vector
        result.push_back(matches[1].str());

        //transform to lower
        for (char &c : result[result.size() - 1])
            c = std::tolower(c);
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    // test the function
    for (auto &word : split_alpha("Sending query: “SELECT * FROM users”"))
        std::cout << word << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
sending
query
select
from
users
```